Laravel Reverb not connecting, everytime I make changes
I just tried laravel reverb, and I noticed that everytime I make some changes in the code, I can't connect to the websocket.
Console Error/Warning
I returned the code back to where I started, but I still can't connect to the websocket. Please do take note that this was working flawlessly when I started.
I checked on the laravel documentation, it said to use this command
php artisan reverb:restart

To reflect the changes. but this doesn't seem working out for me.
Anybody here can help?

I added new public channel:
Broadcast::channel('ewpChanges', function () {
return true;
});

Then created an event:
class ewpChangesEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
 /**
  * Create a new event instance.
  */
 public function __construct(public array $data)
 {
     //
 }

 /**
  * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
  *
  * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
  */
 public function broadcastOn(): array
 {
     return [
         new Channel('ewpChanges'),
     ];
 }

}


Then suddenly I can't connect to the websocket

Did you double-check the reverb setup to make sure it's all good?

My setup was working as intended before I start adding that new channel. Would it still originate from the reverb config?
